# converting iterator of case class to list of another case class

Tags: scala

How to convert iterator of a case class to another case class and convert it to list.

Simply converting iterator into list using .toList does not work in scala 2.12
Error : value toList is not a member of Object

```
case class student(id int, name string)
case class studentNew(studentId int, name string)

val i: Iterator[student] = inputRec
val studentList: List[studentNew] = inputRec.map (s => studentNew(s.id, s.name))  
// To convert to case class of id/name to studentId/name and make a list
```

version scala:2.12

Comment: You are trying to assign an `Iterator` to a `List`. Convert it using `toList` method.

Comment: it does not work on scala 2.12

Comment: As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) is your friend. You just need a `toList` after the `map`

Answer (score 2):

This is a working snippet for `2.12`

```
case class student(id: Int, name: String)
case class studentNew(studentId: Int, name: String)

val inputRec: Iterator[student] = ???
val studentList: List[studentNew] = inputRec.map (s => studentNew(s.id, s.name)).toList
```

You cant assign an `Iterator` to a `List`.